# Installing the latest version of gstreamer and plugins on centos7

Tags: centos7, gstreamer, fedora

I am trying to install the latest version of GStreamer on centos7. There is no official documentation for installing GStreamer on centos but for fedora, ubuntu, and Debian. when I run the installation command for fedora

`dnf install gstreamer1-devel gstreamer1-plugins-base-tools gstreamer1-devel-docs gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel-docs gstreamer1-plugins-good gstreamer1-plugins-good-extras gstreamer1-plugins-ugly gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-devel-docs  gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-devel gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras`

the following things show up the terminal.

```
Package gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel-1.10.4-2.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
Package gstreamer1-plugins-good-1.10.4-2.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
No match for argument: gstreamer1-plugins-good-extras
Package gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-1.10.5-2.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
Package gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-1.10.5-2.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
Package gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.10.4-3.el7.x86_64 is already installed.
No match for argument: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras
Error: Unable to find a match: gstreamer1-plugins-good-extras gstreamer1-plugins
```

The version already installed is very old and doesn't have any of the required libraries for me. After doing some research about it, I've found that the already installed 1.10.4 is the official latest version for centos 7 when I'm supposed to work on centos7 with gstreamer version 1.16.2. Now my question is, is there any way I can install the latest version of the gstreamer on centos7?

Answer (score 0):

use `--best`:

```
dnf --best install gstreamer
```

from the help section:

> **-b, --best**
>
> Try the best available package versions in transactions. Specifically
>   during dnf upgrade, which by default skips over updates that can not
>   be installed for dependency reasons, the switch forces DNF to only
>   consider the latest packages. When running into packages with broken
>   dependencies, DNF will fail giving a reason why the latest version can
>   not be installed.

also make sure to remove the packages that don't exist from your command line... (`No match for argument: gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras` etc)

Comment: adding `-b` doesn't install the latest version for cent os 7, the output is same as before. thanks for you answer though